# SQL: I want a row to be return with NULL even if there is no match to my IN clause

Tags: sql, mybatis, ibatis

I would like my SQL query to return a row even if there is no row matching in my IN clause.

For exemple this query:

```
SELECT id, foo 
FROM table 
WHERE id IN (0, 1, 2, 3)
```

would return:

```
id|foo
 0|bar
 1|bar
 2|bar
 3|null
```

But instead I have (because no row with id 3):

```
id|foo
 0|bar
 1|bar
 2|bar
```

I have been able to find this trick:

```
SELECT tmpTable.id, table.bar
FROM (
    SELECT 0 as id
    UNION SELECT 1
    UNION SELECT 2
    UNION SELECT 3
) tmpTable
LEFT JOIN
( 
SELECT table.foo, table.id 
    FROM table 
    WHERE table.id IN (0, 1, 2, 3)
) table
on table.id = tmpTable.id
```

Is there a better way?

Bonus: How to make it work with myBatis's list variable?

Comment: Unfortunately, your trick is as good as it gets, at least in the standard SQL.

Comment: How are the values in your "in" clause determined? Is it feasible to load all values that you would want to appear in your result set into a separate table, and left join to that? This is a common pattern, similar to having a "Dates" table that contains a record for each day, which can make returning data grouped per day a cinch (and indicate when no data for that day exists).

Answer (score 3):

overslacked is right. Most SQL developers use an auxiliary table that stores integers (and one that stores dates). This is outlined in an entire chapter of Joe Celko's "SQL for Smarties".

Example:

```
CREATE TABLE numeri ( numero INTEGER PRIMARY KEY )

DECLARE @x INTEGER
SET @x = 0
WHILE @x < 1000
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO numeri ( numero ) VALUES ( @x )
  SET @x = @x + 1
END

SELECT
  numero AS id,
  foo
FROM
  numeri
  LEFT OUTER JOIN my_table
    ON my_table.id = numero
WHERE
  numero BETWEEN 0 AND 3
```

Answer (score -1):

Main Goal of Programming minimal code high performance no need this things just remove id 3 from in clause

Answer (score -1):

What about just saying:

SELECT id, foo
FROM table
WHERE id >= 0 AND <= 3